# There is a surplus line in the output of my code - how do I get rid of it? Am I using if and elif incorrectly?

Tags: python

I have only just started to learn Python. I am trying to teach myself so I started making a text based RPG. When the player is choosing their gender if they don't choose the gender that I programmed a response first, they have to enter the gender on the next line? Does that make sense? This is what happens - the user enters female and there is no response. They have to enter female twice to get the response I coded for.

This is the code:

```
print('Please choose your gender')
if raw_input() == ('Male'):
    print('You have chosen male')
elif raw_input() == ('Female'):
    print('You have chosen female')
```

And this is the output:

```
Please choose your gender
Female
```

There is an extra line and I want to get rid of it. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Don't post pictures of your code, paste it here.

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question. Please include text as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Eeek! Sorry - I'll add text instead of pictures next time

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input()` is a function and you're calling it twice, that's why you need to enter "female" twice.

Here is how your code currently works:

1. Output "Please choose your gender"
2. Ask the user for an input
3. If input is "Male" then output "You have chosen male"
4. If the input is not "Male" then ask the user for an input again
5. If the second input is "Female" then output "You have chosen female"

You need to store the outcome of `raw_input()` in a variable and check that instead of calling the function twice.

Comment: Thankyou! That was really clear and obviously well informed

Comment: In fact `raw_input` was never called due to missing brackets.

Comment: @Matthias Actually the post was edited (see the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40357821/revisions)). The code posted originally contained the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You want to save the input. So

```
gender = raw_input()
if gender == "male":
    ...
elif gender == "female":
    ...
else:
    ...
```